# EditText to sqlitenet with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

Im new here.

Quick question, i'll like to extract the values from my inputs and in my table user but it doesn't work. It just takes the default android:text under XAML and put them in instead. What am i doing wrong? 
Much kind regards and thanks for your time.

```
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.create_user);
        inputEmailText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputCreateEmail);
        inputUsernameText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputCreateUsername);
        inputPasswordText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputCreatePassword);
        createUserBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCreateUser);
        showUsersBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShowUsers);

        var tEmail = inputEmailText.Text;
        var tUsername = inputUsernameText.Text;
        var tPassword = inputPasswordText.Text;

        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"users.db4"); //change til db3 change it to another version
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        db.CreateTable<User>();


        // Insert note into the database


        // Show the automatically set ID and message.




        createUserBtn.Click += delegate {
            //  StartActivity(typeof(LoginHomeActivity));
            if (db.Table<User>().Count() == 0)
            {
            user = new User () { Email = tEmail, Username = tUsername, Password = tPassword };
            db.Insert(user);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "The username or email already exist", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        };



        showUsersBtn.Click += delegate {
            //  StartActivity(typeof(LoginHomeActivity));

            var table = db.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM User");
            foreach (var s in table)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.Id + " " + s.Email + " " + s.Username + " " + s.Password);
                Toast.MakeText(this, s.Username, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }

        };
```

Comment: you are initializing your temp variable (tEmail, etc) **before** your user actually enters any data in the form.  You should instead set them inside of your delegate functions.

Comment: Like This? Still doesn't work

createUserBtn.Click += delegate {
            //  StartActivity(typeof(LoginHomeActivity));
                var tEmail = inputEmailText.Text;
                var tUsername = inputUsernameText.Text;
                var tPassword = inputPasswordText.Text;

            if (db.Table<User>().Count() == 0)
            {
            user = new User () { Email = tEmail, Username = tUsername, Password = tPassword };
            db.Insert(user);

            }

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything remotely useful that I could use to help you.  Does it crash?  Does it give an error message?  Does the insert fail?  Does it insert the wrong data?  You need to provide *specific* information if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: It simple skips over to:
Toast.MakeText(this, "The username or email already exist", ToastLength.Short).Show();

Indicating that the email or username is taken.
It still insert "email" "username" and "password" as default inside the database

Comment: It will do that if ANY data exists in the User table.  It will never execute the insert.  So most likely you still have data in that table from your original attempt.  Either clear that table, or modify your logic.

Comment: How to add link [How to add links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/adding-links-to-comments)